# Mock Session is not working in Unit test of Controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nunit, moq

I created a sample ASP.NET MVC application.The default application provided by the Visual Studio.

I created folder named Utilities and place the below 4 classes

1. Connection
2. ConnectionRepository
3. SecurityManager
4. SessionManger

Below are the code of the above classes

```
public class Connection
    {
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        public Connection(string connectionStr)
        {
            this.ConnectionString = connectionStr;
        }
        public User GetUser(string userId)
        {
            return new User() { UserId="User1",Email="User1@company.com" };
        }

    }

******


using LegacyHttpContext = System.Web.HttpContext;

namespace SampleNunitApplication.Utilities
{
    public class ConnectionRepository
    {
        public Connection ConnectionData
        {
            get
            {
                Connection con;
                if(Convert.ToBoolean(LegacyHttpContext.Current.Application["isSourceOffline"].ToString()))
                {
                    con = this.RefreshConfigDataFromAppServer();
                }
                else
                {
                    con = this.RefreshConfigDataFromDB();
                }
                return con;
            }
        }

        public Connection RefreshConfigDataFromDB()
        {
            Connection dbConnection = new Utilities.Connection("DataFromSqlServer");            
            LegacyHttpContext.Current.Application["_connData"] = dbConnection;
            return dbConnection;
        }
        public Connection RefreshConfigDataFromAppServer()
        {
            Connection appConnection = new Utilities.Connection("DataFromAppServer");           
            LegacyHttpContext.Current.Application["_connData"] = appConnection;
            return appConnection;
        }

    }
}

*******


using LegacyHttpContext = System.Web.HttpContext;

namespace SampleNunitApplication.Utilities
{
    public class SecurityManager
    {
        public static SecurityManager GetFromCache()
        {           
            if(LegacyHttpContext.Current.Application["SecurityManager"]==null)
            {
                SecurityManager securityManager = new SecurityManager();
                LegacyHttpContext.Current.Application["SecurityManager"] = securityManager;
                return securityManager;
            }
            else
            {
                return LegacyHttpContext.Current.Application["SecurityManager"] as SecurityManager;
            }

        }

        public User GetAuthenticatedUser(string userId)
        {
            ConnectionRepository connRepository = new ConnectionRepository();
            Connection con = connRepository.ConnectionData;
            return con.GetUser(userId);

        }
    }
}

*****

public class SessionManager
    {
        public string EmployeeId { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public static void SaveToSessionState(HttpSessionStateBase state,SessionManager sessionManager)
        {
            state["SessionManager"] = sessionManager;
        }

        public static SessionManager LoadFromSessionState(HttpSessionStateBase state)
        {
            if (state["SessionManager"] ==null)
            {
                return new SessionManager();
            }
            return state["SessionManager"] as SessionManager;
        }

    }

****In the HomeController.cs***

 public ActionResult Index()
        {           
            SessionManager authenticateUser = SessionManager.LoadFromSessionState(this.HttpContext.Session);
            ValidationModel.Validate(authenticateUser.EmployeeId, this.HttpContext);           
            SessionManager.LoadFromSessionState(this.HttpContext.Session);
            return View();
        }

*******************In the Global.asax***

 protected void Session_Start()
        {
            HttpSessionStateWrapper sessionWrapper = new HttpSessionStateWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session);
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["isSourceOffline"] = false;
            SessionManager authenticateUser = SessionManager.LoadFromSessionState(sessionWrapper);
            User user = SecurityManager.GetFromCache().GetAuthenticatedUser("User1");
            authenticateUser.EmployeeId = user.UserId;
            authenticateUser.Email = user.Email;
            SessionManager.SaveToSessionState(sessionWrapper, authenticateUser);
        }

******

I created a class library project and created below mock code


 [TestClass]    public class UnitTest1

    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var application = new Mock<HttpApplicationStateBase>();
            SecurityManager securityManager = new SecurityManager();
            application.SetupGet(s => s["isSourceOffline"]).Returns(true);
            application.SetupGet(s => s["SecurityManager"]).Returns(securityManager);           
            var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
            var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
            var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
            var session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
            var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();
            session.Setup(s => s.SessionID).Returns(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            context.Setup(c => c.Request).Returns(request.Object);
            context.Setup(c => c.Response).Returns(response.Object);
            context.Setup(c => c.Session).Returns(session.Object);
            context.Setup(c => c.Application).Returns(application.Object);
            context.Setup(c => c.Server).Returns(server.Object);

            SessionManager authenticatedUser = new SessionManager();
            authenticatedUser.EmployeeId = "TestUser";
            authenticatedUser.Email = "Test@testmail.com";
            SessionManager.SaveToSessionState(context.Object.Session, authenticatedUser);
            HomeController objController = new HomeController();
            objController.ControllerContext = new System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext(context.Object, new RouteData(), objController);
            objController.Index();

        }
    }
```

If I run the ASP.NET MVC application it works good. But when i run the test case it hits the Index method of the HomeController but `SessionManager authenticateUser = SessionManager.LoadFromSessionState(this.HttpContext.Session);` is not populating from the session. Properties in the `authenticateUser` are null.

Seems like mock session is not working please help

Comment: Improved readability